# angular/fire getting json by custom field realtime database firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I do have firebase "pages" table, each has unique url ([pages table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNu8Z.png))

```
export class PagesService {

  private dbPath = '/pages';

  pagesRef: AngularFireList<Page> = null;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.pagesRef = db.list(this.dbPath);
  }

  createPage(page: Page): void {
    this.pagesRef.push(page);
  }


  getPagesList(): AngularFireList<Page> {
    return this.pagesRef;
  }

  getPageByUrl(docUrl: string): Page {   <--- this method
      //here i expect to get my json obj from database by field: url, smth like this:
     page: Page = select 1 from db/pages/ where url = docUrl; //pseudo-code
    return page;

  }
}
```

So what actually should i do in getPageByUrl() to get exact json im looking for ?

Comment: There is no "select" in Realtime Database.  You will have to set up a listener at the location you want to query.  You also will not be able to return the value directly from your function since queries are asynchronous.  I suggest starting with the documentation. https://github.com/angular/angularfire#realtime-database

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore), and your description, if you are still designing your app, I would recommend firestore database for your use-case instead of the real-time database if you will need to perform queries and filtration to get data, because such operation on the realtime database are very limited, please check [retrieving data link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and the cost of downloading bytes from the realtime database is very high. [firebase pricing calculator link](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Please check [this link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) to understand how to perform select queries on firestore database using `@angular/fire`

Happy coding!